# Nested Quantifiers: Domain of subjects shared?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have been trying to find some similar questions but couldn't find one.

My question is the following predicate: $\forall$x$\forall$yP(x,y).

Suppose P(x, y):x has written an email to y, my question in this case that I am not sure if the domain of subject is shared between x and y. In my opinion, if we understand nested quantifiers somehow similar to nested loops in CS, I personally think then in this case, x should also have written an email to itself right?

Confused about this concecpt, hope someone can help. Thanks. :)

Comment: yes, you're correct from this statement follows that everyone has also written a letter to themselves.
If you would consider a statement $\forall x \forall y (x \neq y \implies P(x,y))$ with the same property $P$ then that statement would mean that everyone wrote an email to everyone else, except themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed. If we have $\forall x \forall y P(x,y)$, then we do have $P(x,x)$, so $x$ does send an email to itself in your example.

The statement means ‘for all $x$ and for all $y$, $P(x,y)$ is true’, so it is true for *any* pair of $x$ and $y$—including when the two are equal.

Nested quantifiers are kind of similar to nested loops, as you say. We can write your statement as $\forall x [\forall y P(x,y)]$ and then you can indeed view this as asserting $P(x,y)$ for each $y$, for each $x$ just like two nested *for* loops.